# Is nest offline when I'm away?

Tags: nest-api

I've written a combination of bash and php script, which will read the Nest every 5min. I read the values like temp and desired temp and check if it is heating.

This seems to work well as long as the Nest is NOT in "Away" status. When I'm home, I can see a log entry every 5min, but about 45min after I've left my home, the logs don't show any entries anymore. As soon as I get home, I see new entries in the log.

Is it the Away status that is bothering me? Can I somehow change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Being in home or away mode has no effect on the API's responsiveness. You may want to check how you're logging your data

Answer (score 1):

Found why my scripts failed. When the Nest is set to away (either manual or auto), the return object changes.

Away is **active**:

```
[target] => stdClass Object
(
    [mode] => heat
    [temperature] => 18
    [time_to_target] => 0
)
```

Away is **not active**:

```
[target] => stdClass Object
(
    [mode] => range
    [temperature] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10.111
        [1] => 24.444
    )
    [time_to_target] => 0
)
```

So my script is tripping over the array in temperature that is suddenly returned.